# Kernel Crash/ Cpu error?

Tags: linux-mint, crash, kernel-panic, magic-sysrq

First I will describe my system and then my problem:

I have an Assus F555L laptop with an i3 and Intel Integrated Graphics. It is running Linux Mint 17.3 and Windows 10 dual booted. I do not have Grub but just use the UEFI boot menu to boot into Mint or Windows. Now onto my problem

Earlier this morning I booted onto Mint and used it fine. I shutdown and about half an hour later I booted back on. As soon as I was logged on and Cinnamon was running, I tried to connect to a wireless network and the X server and I assume the kernel crashed. Ctl-alt-del would not work, Ctl-alt-f1 would not work, and **commands with the magical sysrq would not work**. I rebooted and could not get it past the login screen without it crashing the same way. I was able to get to tty1 right after a reboot and got these messages:

```
Password [  46.757083] [drm:i915_context_is_banned [i915_bpo]] *Error* gpu hanging to fast, banning!
[   60.071089] NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for 22s! [swapper/0:0]
[   88.052461] NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for 23s! [swapper/0:0]
[   94.763992] INFO: rcu_sched detected stalls on CPUs/tasks {} (detected bu 0, t=15002 jiffies, g=1569, c=1568, q=0)
[   94.764045] INFO: Stall ended before dump start
```

And then, after a few seconds, it refreshed with this:

```
computer_name login: [   116.03333] NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for 23s! [swapper/0:0]
```

What kind of error exactly is this and how can I remedy it?

EDIT:
Tried booting again into tty1. After a long time it had given me all this and then the screen turnes off. Systems still on and harddrive indicator light blinks every so often. Full output is in picture:

[image]

Comment: have a look http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2205211

Comment: Thank you for the help but I believe that problem is unrelated to mine.

Comment: Hi, did you solve this?

Comment: Honestly I don't remember it was so long ago I probably just reinstalled the OS.